# Antique Cast Iron Sink Wall Mounting Support and Weight Issues?

Tags: plumbing, sink

I have an existing stud assembly where a pedestal sink basin was bolted to the wall.  I'm looking to replace it with the (future restored) sink in the photo, but I want to ensure its weight is supported.

Do standard stud/bolt supports work for a sink like this since there are no legs or a pedestal, or is further wall reinforcement needed?

I will definitely be using an iron bracket to attach it.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Antique Cast Iron Sink]

Comment: How heavy is it (no, that isn't a straight line...)? And, how far below those bolt points is the lowest wall support point? I'm wondering about leverage; the shorter the distance, the greater the force pulling the bolts out.

Comment: The sink is approx. 30lbs. I'm not certain what you mean by lowest wall support point.  The existing wall bolts are at about 32-33 inches from the floor.

Comment: When the sink hangs on the wall, the lowest point contacting the wall pushes into the wall, and the bolts are correspondingly pulled out from the wall. These forces hold the sink up. The shorter the distance between these points, the larger the forces need to be to hold up the sink.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed several of these sinks in the past when remodeling turn of the century homes.

They were bolted directly to the studs with ¼” lag bolts that were ~2-1/2 – maybe 3” long. One had a bracket it slipped on to no screws through the back is this the type of bracket you have? that one had 4 nails into the studs.

There was no other support. 
All of the houses had lath and plaster walls at least ½” thick maybe slightly thicker.
One of the sinks still had the ceramic buttons that covered the bolts I believe these are the hardest parts to find originals for.

One caution most of the drains the drains were made from lead pipe and had lead seals. You might want to upgrade the drain to get rid of the lead.

Many of those homes had oak 2X4's but I don't think there will be any problem with pull out with fir or pine studs.

Comment: The sink did not come with the bracket so I'm going to purchase an antique iron one that fits the measurements.  Unless there's some sort of modern wall cleat or bracket that would suffice?  

The sink is about 30lbs. so I'm hoping the current 2x6 with bolts will work.  Thank you for the note on the ceramic buttons, I've been scouring the internet to see what was there originally.